# WP 7 Listbox with 2 cell types

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a listbox with 2 types of cells:
First with a 480X40 px picture and some text on top, to act as a section title.
Second a 480X80 px cell with background, 60X60 image, some text and an arrow.

So my question is how do I accomplish this?
I have thought of 3 solutions:

1. Define a Item Template witch contains all the items from cell 1 and 2 and show/hide the elements when biding.
2. Override the Biding method - this seems to be the correct method, but I have no idea how to  do this.
3. Define 2 Item Templates outside the list box and create, bind and add them at runtime to either an ListBox or ScroolView.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector.

The other approach is to create two different templates and then have a text property on your item view model which contains the name of the template that should be used.  You would then use a ValueConverter to convert from the text name to the actual template.  You can see this described in detail here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/1937/.

Answer (score 0):

Instead working with template, you can create ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for Mango an use implicit data templates.
With this, you can create multiple templates, and at runtime it is determined which one to use according to the type of item given to the ListBox